# Maven dependency with version

Tags: java, maven

In my current maven project I have dependencies which including to output-version.jar file as dependency.jar without version in name, I would like to change name of this dependency to looks like as dependency-version.jar.

Is it possible?

My output-version.jar contains:

- threetenbp.jar
- dependency.jar

  com
     
   site
          
    application
                      
     JavaClass.class

Comment: You would like to create an executable jar ? If so use the maven-assembly-plugin if not flexible enough use maven-shade-plugin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use maven dependency plugin to achieve this : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Thank you for this tip.
That is what I was looking for.

Comment: Happy to help :)